# Looking for full ActiveMerchant AuthorizeNetCimGateway documentation for options requirements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemerchant

I am integrating ActiveMerchant in a project, and am mystified over and over again by the lack of documentation for the options parameter. Taking the following as an example, where do I locate information for what form/format the :payment hash or :payment_profile hash should take. What am I missing here?

```
create_customer_payment_profile(options)
Creates a new customer payment profile for an existing customer profile.

Options
:customer_profile_id — The Customer Profile ID of the customer the payment profile will be added to. (REQUIRED)
:payment_profile — A hash containing the elements of the new payment profile (REQUIRED)
Payment Profile
:payment — A hash containing information on payment. Either :credit_card or :bank_account (REQUIRED)
```

I found the following on someone's blog, and I wonder how I would have been able to infer all of this from the sparse docs on ActiveMerchant. Plus the bill_to isn't even mentioned anywhere in the docs, and seems incomplete below:

```
@profile = {:customer_profile_id => self.user.customer_cim_id,
            :payment_profile => {:bill_to => self.address,
                                 :payment => {:credit_card => CreditCard.new(self.credit_card)}
                                 }
```

Comment: There's always reading the source. A bit bogus and fragile but sometimes necessary.

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing. Saved my sanity. Sometimes reading 700 lines of source code is easier that scouring the web for someone whose also read the source, and then wrote good documentation :)

Comment: The problem with reading the source is that it doesn't distinguish between guaranteed specified behavior and accidental behavior. But hey, you do what you gotta' do.

Comment: wow, just researched the exact same problem 10 years later, and found my question, haha. Here's to bad documentation.